# Visual Studio Code Analysis: CA0001 Error Running Code Analysis - object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: code-analysis

For a WPF application being developed in VS 2012 (Ultimate), the application runs fine when a particular project's code analysis is disabled. Enabling it results in the error above.

This was working fine until recently (i.e. running with code analysis enabled for the particular project) and the only recent change I can think of is removing NHibernate Profiler (using NuGet).

Will be grateful for any pointers on how to debug this, or to see a more detailed log/error message.

Comment: It could also be a problem in the rules themselves: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245246.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the following code:

```
IContact contact = personViewModel.Model ?? companyViewModel.Model;
```

rewriting it in a different format resolved the issue:

```
IContact person = personViewModel.Model;
Icontact company = companyViewModel.Model;
IContact contact = person ?? company;
```

I am not sure why code analysis tripped up on it when it otherwise compiled and ran fine.

I found the offending code (code analysis giving absolutely no clue apart from indicating which project) by using source control to selectively update a recent working copy.